# Using docker secrets in docker container of PHP app

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-secrets

I am trying to deploy my PHP app in the docker container. Using docker secret I want to store the password of the MySQL database. First I created a docker secret mysql_password. My docker-compose file is -

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    php:
        image: 'php:7.2-fpm'
        build:
            context: ./docker
            dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - './app:/var/www/html'
        environment:
            MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_password
        secrets:
            - mysql_password

    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - '80:80'
        links:
            - 'php'
        volumes:
            - './app:/var/www/html'
            - './config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d'
secrets:
    mysql_password:
        external: true
```

- When I try to access the secret  'mysql_password' is is not returning anything. And if I try environment element 'MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE', it is giving me the path of secret that is '/run/secrets/mysql_password'.
- To access environment variable in PHP I have used .$_ENV["mysql_password"]

Answer (score 0):

change `:` to `=` like in regular environment file.

```
MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mysql_password
```

You can use env variable as well:

```
env_file:
     - ./application_env.env
```

and put all variables to that file.

Comment: I am trying to access the secret stored in file /run/secrets/mysql_password. If I change : to =, still I get path of secret file that is '/run/secrets/mysql_password'

Comment: Setting a env variable doesn't create a file. In this case you had set env variable `MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE` with value `/run/secrets/mysql_password`. If you want add this file you have to create it or mont it. Mont example: `./mysql_password:/run/secrets/mysql_password`

Comment: I set secret using command 
 `echo "my_password" | docker secret create mysql_password.` In my docker compose file accessing the secrets  -
 `environment:
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE=  /run/secrets/mysql_password.`
In PHP file when I try  .$_ENV["mysql_password"] it gives blank string and on  .$_ENV["MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE"] it gives /run/secrets/mysql_password.
How can I get "my_password" in PHP file.